# strange error when I change view after some time

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a bigo problem, I have a navigation based app that read end edit value from a database, I read value (from table1) then disaply 1 button for value, on click open e new view with a button for all value of another table and the I open a detail view.On detail view I edit some value of database but I think is not the problem...after some time I open/close the detail view I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/kikko/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/36424126-8725-4DDA-8D58-736A407E1F37/ObjectQuiz.app> (loaded)' with name 'OggettoController''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x137f022 0x1937cd6 0x1327a48 0x13279b9 0x5ba638 0x4601fc 0x460779 0x46099b 0x460d11 0x4728fd 0x472aef 0x472dbb 0x47385f 0x473e06 0x473a24 0x604a 0x1380e99 0x39c14e 0x39c0e6 0x442ade 0x442fa7 0x442266 0x65da1a 0x135399e 0x12ea640 0x12b64c6 0x12b5d84 0x12b5c9b 0x22717d8 0x227188a 0x399626 0x2a92 0x2a05)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

the strange problem is that I have this problem only after tot clic (not on the same button)...can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

I usually see this when I've left a reference in a nib to an outlet that no longer exists in the class.  You can get more information by setting a an "all exceptions" breakpoint (go to the breakpoints tab in the project navigator, press + at the bottom left).

That will narrow down which xib where to look.  Then look carefully at the xib's connection inspector.  Look for any of your outlets that has a little "!" on the link.

Comment: I look for ! on xib but nothing....using breakpoint I get the error here:     [self.navigationController pushViewController:oggettoController animated:YES]; what I don't understand is why I get the error after some click and not on the first click...:(

Comment: Not sure about the timing, but the oggettoController xib definition has a bad reference in it.  If the outlets are good, maybe it's a custom class that no longer exists.  Go thru the view hierarchy and check those.

Comment: I so some test, and I think a possible error, I use notification for update a button and I don't remove the observe, probably is this (is possible for you?) I do an nslog of the notification userinfo and evry time I update the button the dic have more value (instead only one)